# How to close SurfaceView without closing the context Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

An activity opens the SurfaceView class passing the context. I want to close de SurfaceView keeping the first activity alive.

```
((Activity) getContext()).finish();
```

This close the parent activity. How can I close only de SurfaceView ?

Comment: You cannot close a SurfaceView, it doesn't work like an Activity. Or do you want to hide it?

Comment: Setting the SurfaceView to null should kill it in most circumstances.

Comment: Then if I want to show the parent Activity after closing the SurfaceView, I need to reopen it ?

Comment: Um, the parent activity never left. It's still present but can't display what's not there.

Comment: If you mean "closing the SurfaceView activity", then yes, you will need to restart it.

Comment: Then, how can I call a method in the first Activity from the SurfaceView?

Comment: Wait, what? I'm so confused. What is your end game plan? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can create a custom Listener and send an event to the activity.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain better. The Activity that call the SurfaceView is a Stage Chooser. If the player loose, the activity will close, but if the player Clear the screen, I want to keep the Stage Chooser after the SurfaceView.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand... Can you show some code about how you "call" the SurfaceView?

Comment: setContentView(new GameView(this, db.getStage(nStage)));

Comment: Mmm...maybe it's better to create another Activity to add the GameView (SurfaceView ) and open this new Activity from the Stage Chooser, and not open the SurfaceView from the Stage Chooser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, setContentView() should be called only once per Activity, in the onCreate() method. If you need to change the layout completely, then create another Activity, and you won't run into problems like that.

So, to solve your problem, create a dedicated activity for your SurfaceView that you can close safely without worrying about closing your Stage Chooser in the same time.