# Closing surfaceview without an error

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game i have a`Surfaceview`extended class which have `gameloop`and all its attributes class my game is running good too. but when the stage ends i want to click back button and exit to another level select page . i used intent to navigate to my menu . my application is working but i get a force close when i do it ! how to do it without an error ! here is my codes

```
   @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     oursong.release();


     Intent easycamp = new Intent(GamedaActivity.this,Easymode.class);
     startActivity(easycamp);
        }
```

when i do this my`Surfaceview` class and my`gameloop`throws a error ! 
even after the error my game runs and goes to the level select page but it throws a error . so i want to get rid of it to make it clean and smooth

i have a java null pointer exception error and followed by my`SurfaceView` in `ondraw();` method and `gameloop` have error in `run();` method

i already tryed using `finish();` but no use .

Comment: add some comment before give negative points ! i will correct it !

Comment: "force close" -> please post exception stacktrace from logcat

Comment: `11-27 17:53:16.695: E/AndroidRuntime(489): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 17:53:16.695: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at com.workplease.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:173)
11-27 17:53:16.695: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at com.workplease.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:31)`

Answer (score 0):

SetContentView() should be called only once per Activity, in the onCreate() method. If you need to change the layout completely, then create another Activity, and you won't run into problems like that.

So, to solve your problem, create a dedicated activity for your SurfaceView that you can close safely without worrying about closing your Stage Chooser in the same time.

from-[How to close SurfaceView without closing the context Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189670/how-to-close-surfaceview-without-closing-the-context-activity)

Comment: i have 2 activities  first one is with a `xml` layout that select levels and the `secondactivity` is my base activity for my game which sets its view to a` surfaceview `the code i wrote here is in my second activity that has the view set to surfaceview

Comment: from my `gamedaactivity` i want to go to my ` easymode` activity when i press back